# Use Mergetool in JGit

Tags: git, jgit, merge-conflict-resolution

I want to resolve a merge conflict using a specific mergetool in JGit.
On the commandline you would simply do

```
git mergetool
```

But I haven't found any way to do this in JGit.
Is this functionality supported by JGit?
So far I haven't found any questions or bugreports about this.
No one seems to be missing this functionality.

Comment: I see you're new to SO If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Comment: Ah right, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JGit is a Java-only implementation of Git. If `git mergetool` was supported, the various native mergetools would need to be included, for each platform on which JGit is possibly executed. I think this is the reason why this is not implemented.

In addition, [EGit](https://www.eclipse.org/egit/) - probably the primary JGit consumer - uses the [Eclipse Compare Editor](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-25.htm) to resolve conflicts and thus has no need for a mergetool, AFAIK.

Here is a discussion about adding mergetool support to EGit:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=356832

If you think this should be implemented in JGit, please [file an enhancement request](https://eclipse.org/jgit/support/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, do you know any other git librarys, maybe for another languages which supports mergetools?

Comment: If know of [libgit2](http://libgit2.github.com/), but I doubt that this library or any library supports mergetool as this usually is an interactive process and would tie a library to a certain platform or UI toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote to the JGit mailing list and got an answer by a developer also saying that this feature is not yet supported by JGit, but he's working on it trying to integrate it by March.